# Is there a standard what to write first: the @RequestBody or the @PathVariable?

Tags: spring, rest, coding-style, standards, code-cleanup

If you have a function with `@RequestBody` and `@PathVariable` in a function.
Is there any standard, which to write first? I haven't found anything while searching for it.

Is it better to put `@PathVariable` first

```
public void save (@PathVariable("pathVariable") String pathVariable, @RequestBody String requestBody) {}
```

or better putting `@RequestBody` first?

```
public void save (@RequestBody String requestBody, @PathVariable("pathVariable") String pathVariable) {}
```

Comment: Doesn't really matter.

Comment: I find it more natural to put the path variable first. It comes before in the HTTP request. But maybe I'm weird.

Comment: I'm with Mr. Nizet :)

Comment: I know, that it doesn't matter... just wanted to know if there is something like a "common best way" to do it... the explanation from @JBNizet makes sense to me!